# Is there a simple way to make these two lines into a one-liner?

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

Here are the two lines:

```
pixels[x-left] = {};
pixels[x-left][y] = true;
```

It would greatly allow me to clean up some code if the two could be combined into a single expression.

My first attempt looked something like this:

```
pixels[x-left] = { y: true };
```

However the letter `y` is being used as the index instead of the value of `y`, which is not OK.

Comment: @Abbas `y` is a variable.

Comment: This is an often asked question. Duplicate with the most upvotes I could find: [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start right off saying that Bergi's solution should be preferred, but in case you don't mind killing your code's readability:

```
(pixels[x-left] = {})[y] = true;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yWUuE/1/)

This works as an [assignment expression](http://es5.github.io/x11.html#x11.13.1) returns the assigned value (in this case, a reference to the assigned object).

Comment: Aw, nice :-) Of course that changes the statement value, but it shouldn't matter

Comment: There's a semi-colon after the statement and I hope it is not part of another expression so yes, it assumes the expression's return value isn't significant. `=]`

Comment: It's not "pretty", but it's what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is <s>not</s> no clean one*. Any property name in an object literal is interpreted literally.

One way out would be some kind of helper function, like

```
Object.set = function(o, p, v) { o[p] = v; return o; };

pixels[x-left] = Object.set({}, y, true);
```

but then everybody reading your code would need to know about `Object.set`.

<sub>* After @Fabricio's answer I can't state "no possibility" any more :-)</sub>

Comment: +1 for not murdering Antarctica's seals. `=]` And rofl at the mention. `xD`